# Silverlight : COM Exception while loading a resource dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, resourcedictionary

Just stumbled on an error that I can't seem to get rid of. I wanted to share it and check if that was just me or if anyone knew a workaround.

Context:

I have a scenario where I create a base class for user controls (abstract and inheriting from `UserControl`). While that base class has no XAML itself, I wish to load a resource dictionary containing styles that will be used by all child classes. Therefore I have to load this resource dictionary and load it in the merged resource dictionaries from my class C# code.

To reproduce the problem :

- Create a new Silverlight 5 application with default settings (tested on VS2013 SP4)
- Create a new resource dictionary at the root of the project. The name of the file is unimportant
- Get to the MainPage code behind, and add these lines at the end of the constructor:

  ```
  ResourceDictionary dic = new ResourceDictionary();
  Uri source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
  dic.Source = source;
  ```
- Run the solution. The project should crash at the last line of that snippet above, throwing an instance of the actual `System.Exception` class, with the message "*Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.*" Stack trace and trace output are unhelpful.

I've tried different things like waiting for the `Loaded` event, different kinds of Uris, but couldn't find any working variant.

So there you go. I'd be happy if anyone has an explanation, or has an idea about a different way to add a merged resource dictionary from C#.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the source object is not null?